# How can I find the color color created with bitmask?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bitmask

how can I find the color created with bitmask?
For example, what is the color equivalent of this expression?

```
color = -16777216
```

Comment: It depends how the color is encoded. Is it RBG-encoded? CMYK?

Comment: `new Color(color, true)` - as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,boolean)): "*Creates an sRGB color with the specified combined RGBA value consisting of the alpha component in bits 24-31, the red component in bits 16-23, the green component in bits 8-15, and the blue component in bits 0-7.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with Integer.toHexString.

```
val bitmaskColor = -16777216
Log.e("HEX",Integer.toHexString(bitmaskColor)) // ff000000
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends entirely on the underlying pixel format. Without knowing that crucially important information it's impossible to answer!

Without knowing the color space and pixelformat being used, you can't answer that.

---

For the sake of argument lets assume that the pixel format was little endian, RGBA with 8 bits per channel packed into a single 32 bit value with red in the least significant bits and alpha in the most significant ones.

The binary representation of `-16777216` in 2s complement would be

```
b_11111111_00000000_00000000_00000000
```

or in hexadecimal

```
h_ff000000
```

According to the pixelformat we assumed that would be A=100%, R=B=G=0%, i.e. a fully opaque black.